# count values and the reset the count value in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, count, epplus

Hello im trying to count items in a excel sheet.
I extract the info from various excel files and this works just fine, but now  i want to
count the items in the DUS variable (column G), but based on the NAVE column(A column in
the excel ) and the AREA column(column B in the excel): this is the code i use to extract the info from other excel files and generate my total excel file:

```
       Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
        Dim path As String = seleccionardirectorio("Excel|.xlsx")
        If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) = False) Then

            Dim excel = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(path))
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Resultado")
            ' excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Resultado2")
            Dim aux As Integer = 1

            Dim Workbook = excel.Workbook
            Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets
            Dim hoja1 = Workbook.Worksheets("Resultado")
           

            While (aux <= NAVE.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("A" & aux + 6).Value = NAVE.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While

            aux = 1

            While (aux <= NAVE2.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("I" & aux + 6).Value = NAVE2.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While

            aux = 1

            While (aux <= NAVE2.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("K" & aux + 6).Value = NAVE2.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While

            aux = 1

            While (aux <= AREA.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("B" & aux + 6).Value = AREA.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While
            aux = 1

            While (aux <= ENTREGA.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("C" & aux + 6).Value = ENTREGA.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While
            aux = 1

            While (aux <= DESTINO.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("D" & aux + 6).Value = DESTINO.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While
            aux = 1

            While (aux <= RESERVA.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("E" & aux + 6).Value = RESERVA.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While
            aux = 1


            While (aux <= DESPACHO.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("F" & aux + 6).Value = DESPACHO.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While
            aux = 1


            While (aux <= DUS.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("G" & aux + 6).Value = DUS.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1
            End While
            aux = 1


           
            Dim aux2 As Integer = 1
            Dim bandera As Boolean = False
            Dim n_planillas As String = ""
            Dim indice As Integer = 1



            While (aux <= NAVE2.Count)

                If hoja1.Cells("B" & aux + 6).Value = "PANL" Then
                    hoja1.Cells("J" & aux + 6).Value = DUS_CONT.Count
                Else
                    hoja1.Cells("L" & aux + 6).Value = DUS_CONT.Count
                End If
                aux += 1
            End While

            aux = 1

            hoja1.Cells("I2").Value = "ENTREGAS"


            hoja1.Cells("I1").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I5:J5").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("K5:L5").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I5:J5").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Pink)
            hoja1.Cells("K5:L5").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightBlue)


            hoja1.Cells("I6:J6").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("K6:L6").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I6:J6").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Pink)
            hoja1.Cells("K6:L6").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightBlue)


            hoja1.Cells("I1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Green)
            hoja1.Cells("I2").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I2").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow)
            hoja1.Cells("I3").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I3").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow)
            hoja1.Cells("I4").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I4").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow)

            hoja1.Cells("I3").Value = "DESPACHOS"
            hoja1.Cells("J1").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("J1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Green)
            hoja1.Cells("J4").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("J4").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow)
            hoja1.Cells("J2").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("J2").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow)
            hoja1.Cells("J3").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("J3").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow)


            hoja1.Cells("I4").Value = "DUS"
            hoja1.Cells("I5").Value = "MADERAS"
            hoja1.Cells("K5").Value = "CELULOSA"
            hoja1.Cells("I6").Value = "NAVE"
            hoja1.Cells("J6").Value = "TOTAL"
            hoja1.Cells("K6").Value = "NAVE"
            hoja1.Cells("L6").Value = "TOTAL"



            hoja1.Cells("J2").Value = ENTREGA_CONT.Count
            hoja1.Cells("J3").Value = DUS_CONT.Count 'DESPACHO_CONT.Count
            hoja1.Cells("J4").Value = DUS_CONT.Count

             excel.Save()
                MsgBox("Documento Creado Correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, 
            Title:="Operacion Correcta")
                Process.Start(path)
            End If
            
     Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

    NAVE.Clear()
    AREA.Clear()
    ENTREGA.Clear()
    DESTINO.Clear()
    RESERVA.Clear()
    DESPACHO.Clear()
    DUS.Clear()
    NAVE_CONT.Clear()
    AREA_CONT.Clear()
    ENTREGA_CONT.Clear()
    DESTINO_CONT.Clear()
    RESERVA.Clear()
    DESPACHO_CONT.Clear()
    DUS_CONT.Clear()

    MsgBox("Documentos Eliminados Correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Operacion Exitosa")

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Public Sub INICIALIZAR_PLANILLA(ByRef HOJAUSUARIOS As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet)
    Try
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("A1").Value = "NAVE"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("B1").Value = "AREA"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("C1").Value = "ENTREGA"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("D1").Value = "DESTINO"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("E1").Value = "RESERVA"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("F1").Value = "DESPACHO"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("G1").Value = "DUS"

        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("I1").Value = "DOCUMENTO"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("J1").Value = "TOTAL"


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
Public Function seleccionardirectorio(ByVal filtro As String) As String

    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = filtro
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Seleccione Directorio"
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Return saveFileDialog1.FileName
End Function

Public Function EXTRAER_PLANILLAS(ByRef ruta As String) As Boolean
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
    Try
        Dim stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(ruta)
        Dim package = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(stream)
        '//  Libro
        Dim Workbook = package.Workbook
        '//  Hojas
        Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets

        ' While (Workbook.Worksheets.Count >= aux)
        Dim hojaUsuarios2 = Workbook.Worksheets(Workbook.Worksheets.Item(0).ToString)
        Dim indice As Integer = 0
        Dim indice2 As Integer = 1
        '  NAVE.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("H7").Value)
        'NAVE.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("H7").Value)
        NAVE2.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("H7").Value)
        While (indice < 700)

            'Numero SPS'
            'If (acotar(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value, indice)) Then
            'If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("H7").Value) = False) Then

            'End If
            ''End If
            ''numero planilla'
            'If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
            'If (hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 11).Value = hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 1 + 11).Value = False) Then
            'If hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 11).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
            '    Console.WriteLine("prueba")
            'End If
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
                AREA.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 11).Value)
            End If

            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
                NAVE.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("H7").Value)
            End If
            'End If
            '    'IDCONTENEDOR'
            '    If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
            '   If (hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + 11).Value = hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + indice2 + 11).Value = False) Then
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
               
                ENTREGA.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + 11).Value)
            End If

            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
                If (hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + 11).Value = hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + 1 + 11).Value = False) Then
                    ENTREGA_CONT.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("E" & indice + 11).Value)
                End If
            End If
                'PAQUETE2'
                If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("G" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
                DESTINO.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("G" & indice + 11).Value)

            End If
            'RESERVA
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("H" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then

                RESERVA.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("H" & indice + 11).Value)
            End If

            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then

                DESPACHO.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("K" & indice + 11).Value)
            End If

            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("K" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
                DESPACHO_CONT.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("K" & indice + 11).Value)
            End If
            'If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("L" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then

            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("B" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
                DUS.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("L" & indice + 11).Value)

            End If
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("L" & indice + 11).Value) = False) Then
                DUS_CONT.Add(hojaUsuarios2.Cells("L" & indice + 11).Value)
            End If

            indice += 1

        End While

        Dim aux4 As Integer = 0


    Catch EX As Exception
        MsgBox(EX.ToString)
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True

End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

so now if i want count i need to count the items of DUS but if the ship changes in the index  i have to reset the counter and move to the next ship
so if i have data like this in the excel:

| NAVE | AREA | DUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MOL BEN | CASA | 900 |
| MOL BEN | CASA | 901 |
| MOL BEN | PANL | 922 |
| MOL BEN | CASA | 934 |
| MOL BEN | CASA | 942 |
| MSN AIN | PANL | 1530 |
| MSN AIN | PANL | 1540 |
| MSN AIN | CASA | 1544 |
| MSN AIN | CASA | 1544 |
| MSN AIN | CASA |  |

so i would need to say in the generated excel that the total that the ship MOL BEN in the type CASA has 4 DUS items and in the type PANL has 1 DUS item.

In the ship MSN AIN in the type CASA has 2 DUS items and in the type PANL has 2 DUS items.

In the excel, the ship could be anything so i can't use the names to do validations

in the type it would always be either CASA OR PANL

in this code i prepared the excel to receive the counted info

in the list NAVE2 are al ships. This code is to fill the place in the excel where the data is going to go.

```
 hoja1.Cells("I1").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I5:J5").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("K5:L5").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I5:J5").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Pink)
            hoja1.Cells("K5:L5").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightBlue)


            hoja1.Cells("I6:J6").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("K6:L6").Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            hoja1.Cells("I6:J6").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Pink)
            hoja1.Cells("K6:L6").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightBlue)

           hoja1.Cells("I4").Value = "DUS"
            hoja1.Cells("I5").Value = "MADERAS"
            hoja1.Cells("K5").Value = "CELULOSA"
            hoja1.Cells("I6").Value = "NAVE"
            hoja1.Cells("J6").Value = "TOTAL"
            hoja1.Cells("K6").Value = "NAVE"
            hoja1.Cells("L6").Value = "TOTAL"
```

and here is a semi-idea about how to start to solve it

```
 While (aux <= NAVE2.Count)

                If hoja1.Cells("B" & aux + 6).Value = "PANL" Then
                    hoja1.Cells("J" & aux + 6).Value = DUS_CONT.Count
                Else
                    hoja1.Cells("L" & aux + 6).Value = DUS_CONT.Count
                End If
                aux += 1
            End While

            aux = 1
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You have asked a dozen questions and not accepted a single answer? Either SO has gone way down hill or you are not accepting answers.

Comment: A much easier method in my opinion, if you're wanting to do any sort of data analysis/parsing.  Pull your spreadsheet into in memory collections of classes.  Then it's real simply to do this sort of analysis via common tools such as Linq queries